# React UseEffect - How to empty an array when i select an Item from dropown

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

This is my current situation.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

     if (!home.matchsPlayed || !home.totalCal || !selectedHomeName) {
       return ;
     }

     setData(prev =>
       prev.concat([
         {
           day: home.matchsPlayed,
           [selectedHomeName]: home.totalCal
         }
       ])
     );
   },[home.matchsPlayed, home.totalCal, selectedHomeName]);
```

I an create an array on my first loading page, when `home.matchsPlayed`, `home.totalCal` and `selectedHomeName` are not **undefined**. Here below the `console.log('Data Array', data);` output example

```
  data: [
    {day:1, Barcelona:0},
    {day:2, Barcelona:1},
    {day:3, Barcelona:4}
  ],
```

My problem is that i want this `useEffect` running only on my first loading
because then I can select an other item/team from a dropdown and **i want to make 2 actions**

1. Clean the existing data array ( created from he previous `useEffect`)
2. Set a new one with the item/team
       states anytime i select a new item/team from the dropdown

Example:

```
let emptyData = []
setData([...data]);
```

and again

```
 setData(prev =>
   prev.concat([
     {
       day: home.matchsPlayed,
       [selectedHomeName]: home.totalCal
     }
   ])
 );
```

This is the method when i select a new item from the dropdown

```
  const [selectedHomeOption, setSelectedHomeOption] = useState("");
  const [selectedHomeName, setSelectedHomeName] = useState("");

  const selectHomeTeamStat = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    const item = items.find(item => item.team_id == value);
    setSelectedHomeOption(value);
    setSelectedHomeName(item.name);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Home Team name:', selectedHomeName, 'Home Team Option:', selectedHomeOption);
    getStats(leagueId, selectedHomeOption, 'home');
  },[selectedHomeName, selectedHomeOption, home.matchsPlayed, home.totalCal]);
```

I am not sure if i am on the right path to achieve that, so i need any suggestion and code solution from experts.

Comment: What do you do when you select an item from dropdown? do you set any of `home.matchsPlayed, home.totalCal, selectedHomeName`

Comment: I put the code in the question

Comment: Interaction cose and UseEffect to select the item added in the question

Comment: @Koala7 As far as I understand, you want your `useEffects` to run only once for the first time. Later on, whenever the state is updated, you don't want this to run. Is it?

Comment: correct because i have conflicts then and i believe i can handle everything in my second useEffect when i send the requests, but i am not a react expert so i do not know what is best actually or if there is a easier an cleaner solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we create another state to denote if the code that we don't want to be executed later on doesn't run? Something like this:

```
 const [isStateDirty, setStateDirty] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!isStateDirty){
       //Execute this code. This will be done only for the first time
    }
  });



//Below is any other method that gets called after which I don't want the code in useEffect to run.

const myAnyOtherMethod = () =>{
    setStateDirty(true); //this will set the state to true making sure the code in the `useEffects` doesn't run now.
}
```

Comment: The setData part where it should be defined? if you can provide to me the answer with the complete code that i have used to better understand i would appreciate

Comment: @Koala7 So What I'm thinking is this:

Run the code in the `useEffect` for the first time by wrapping it with `isStateDirty ` flag. Later in any other method, say, `selectHomeTeamStat ` you change `isStateDirty`. After that the code in the `useEffect` that was wrapped with this flag wouldn't execute.

Comment: i try later and let you know to accept the answer in case, thanks